# Sending UDP package to Lifx and recvfrom

Tags: c++, networking

I am trying to send a broadcast UDP package to all my Lifx devices (wifi lamps). The devices should answer with another package to the same port I sent the first package from.

I am so far, that I see my sent broadcast package in wireshark. I also see the reply from the Lifx lamp.

But my program is stuck on `recvfrom`.

```
int sockfd;
struct sockaddr_in saddr_send, saddr_recv;

if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0 ) {
    perror("socket creation failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int one = 1;

if ((setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (void*) &one, sizeof(one))) < 0 ) {
    perror("set socket option failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if ((setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, &one, sizeof(one))) < 0 ) {
    perror("set socket option failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

memset(&saddr_send, 0, sizeof(saddr_send));
memset(&saddr_recv, 0, sizeof(saddr_recv));

// Filling dest information
saddr_send.sin_family = AF_INET; // IPv4
saddr_send.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_BROADCAST;
saddr_send.sin_port = htons(PORT);

// Filling source information
saddr_recv.sin_family = AF_INET; // IPv4
saddr_recv.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
saddr_recv.sin_port = htons(PORT);

// Bind the socket with the server address
if (bind(sockfd, (const struct sockaddr *)&saddr_recv, sizeof(saddr_recv)) < 0 ) {
    perror("bind failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

char buffer[BUFF_SIZE];
size_t length;

unsigned size = sizeof(saddr_recv);
char recvbuffer[BUFF_SIZE];

length = sendMessage->getEncodedHeader(buffer, BUFF_SIZE);
int e = sendto(sockfd, buffer, length, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &saddr_send, sizeof(saddr_send));

if (e < 0) {
    printf("%i\n", errno);
    perror("Send error: ");
}

unsigned int r = recvfrom(sockfd, (void*)&recvbuffer, sizeof(recvbuffer), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&saddr_recv, &size);

if (r < sizeof(lifx_protocol_header)) {
    printf("package too short");
}

close(sockfd);
```

I am not sure if I made a conceptional mistake or if I am to slow with calling `recvfrom`.

Any idea on additional points I could try to solve my problem?

Comment: You checked the firewall ?

Comment: @RichardCritten I disabled the firewall.

Comment: What's the error code? Check the manpage to get some insight into how to do that. Oh, and please provide a [mcve]!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Not sure what you want from OP. They gave MCVE, and there is likely no error code - just `recvfrom()` bocked.

Comment: I don't know where you see anything complete (i.e. compilable), @SergeyA. I'm also not interpreting "stuck on recvfrom" as a call that doesn't return, hence I'm asking for a clarification.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt how is the question you mark a duplicat of mine? The only common ground is UDP and sockets. The problem is a different one.

Comment: Sorry, Pascal, but I didn't do that. I did vote to close (MCVE missing) but it was probably rather SergeyA that closed it as duplicate.

Comment: @Pascal, I closed it as a duplicate. I  assumed, you are not getting the broadcasts because you didn't bind to the proper interface. However, I am having second thoughts now, I will reopen.

Comment: @SergeyA No I bound to the right port etc. (or at least I assume I did) That's why I see the response from the light in wireshark. My problem is, that recvfrom does not return, which it should.

Comment: @SergeyA thanks for opening it again